# How to display first post

Tags: loop

I want to display in the front page of my theme the first most recent post in the header  and then continuing the loop in the main content section starting from the second to post and so on, how can i achieve this?

Comment: There are a number of questions here about formatting the first "n" posts differently. Look to right under "Related", though they may not be exactly what you are after. I have addressed similar things [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77707/21376), [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77707/21376), [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82176/21376), and other places as well I believe. Some of those might help (but @Milo's answer got my upvote)

Answer (score 3):

Calling `the_post()` is what advances the internal `current_post` counter that `have_posts()` checks the value of within the loop.

With this in mind, you can call `the_post()` once outside the loop and use any template tags you wish, then run the loop as normal and it will pick up and continue from the second post.

```
the_post();
// this is the first post!
the_title();

// now the loop
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    // starts at 2nd post
    the_title();
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set a new query and play with the parameter offset [see documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

```
'offset' => 1
```

will exclude the most recent post for example.